# How to solve $c_1 me^{mL}+ c_2 (-m)e^{-mL}= -(h/k)(c_1 e^{mL} +c_2 e^{-mL})$?

Tags: calculus

$c_1 me^{mL}+ c_2 (-m)e^{-mL}= -(h/k)(c_1 e^{mL} +c_2 e^{-mL})$

Where L is  variable, e is constant of the base of natural logarithm and everything else is constant.

Label the name of your method of solving.

I couldn't find the method on how to do this in any textbook.

This comes from analytical heat transfer by Han, Chin

Comment: Multiply both sides by $e^{mL}$ and separate

Comment: @AhmedHussein More hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplying both sides by $e^{mL}$ and separating,

$$e^{2mL} = \frac{c_2}{c_1} \frac{mk - h}{mk + h}$$

This has a solution provided that the RHS is $>0$ (I'll be assuming that everything is well-defined so that a solution exists and everything works well), in which case, taking logarithm,

$$2mL = \ln \left( \frac{c_2}{c_1} \frac{mk - h}{mk + h} \right)$$

i.e.

$$L = \frac{1}{2m} \ln \left( \frac{c_2}{c_1} \frac{mk - h}{mk + h} \right)$$